# Can i drop partition without losing data in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning

Query is related to list partition. I have 600 tables and each of them stored in list partition. Question is - can i drop partition without losing data?

Comment: I suppose you could if the partition contained no rows, but that would be quite an unusual situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have 600tables data stored in list partition"? 600 different tables and each of them is partitioned by list?

Comment: a partition is basically a table, if you don't move the data first, yes you'll lose it

Comment: Yes 600 different tables and each of them is partitioned by list

Comment: Where do you think your data will reside after you've dropped some partition (not to lose it)? Please, describe the final result you want to achieve, maybe you are looking for wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

If your partition has data you will lose them.
If your partition is empty you will not have any problem.

Regards.